# Convert array to WrappedArray

Tags: scala

I have tried to use WrappedArray and initialize it by null

```
var classes:WrappedArray [String]= null
 var classe = ENTEleveClasses.apply(0)
         if(!classe.isEmpty()) {
           var cls = classe.split(",")
           for(c <- cls){
             classes =   classes :+ c  //  the error 
           }
           classes
         }else ENTEleveClasses
```

Error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at comptesInvites.EleveENT$$anonfun$1.apply(EleveENT.scala:19)
    at comptesInvites.EleveENT$$anonfun$1.apply(EleveENT.scala:16)
    ... 16 more
```

when I add an element a WrappedArray an Error occurred

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always try to avoid initializing variables with `null` as it leads to numerous `nullpointerExceptions` and [can even damage a system as a whole](http://everythingsysadmin.com/2009/01/tony-hoare-apologizes-for-inve.html).

You should initialize the `WrappedArray` `classes` as

```
var classes:mutable.WrappedArray [String]= mutable.WrappedArray.empty[String]
```

Comment: Thank you @Ramesh, I remove mutable so the variable becomes var classes:WrappedArray [String]=WrappedArray.empty[String]

Comment: I am glad that it helped you @MounirHamdane :) An upvote would help me too :)

Comment: "can even damage a system as a whole."?

Comment: @JosiahYoder check out [Tony Hoare](http://everythingsysadmin.com/2009/01/tony-hoare-apologizes-for-inve.html)

Answer (score 0):

`when I add an element a WrappedArray an Error occurred`

You're not adding an element to a WrappedArray, you're adding an element to the null value, which is indeed impossible, and generates a NPE.

To add an element to a WrappedArray, you have to actually provide one, so instead of `var classes:WrappedArray [String]= null`, use `var classes:WrappedArray [String]= new WrappedArray()` (I'm not actually sure what are the constructors for WrappedArray, you may have to change this !)